# Test if Beta feature of Generating faster code is enabled

Tags: java, performance, hadoop, avro, avro-tools

On the Avro Docs it is mentioned that:- to turn new approach to generating code that speeds up decoding and encoding set feature flag/system flag `org.apache.avro.specific.use_custom_coders` to true at runtime.([here](https://avro.apache.org/docs/1.11.1/getting-started-java/#beta-feature-generating-faster-code)).

Enquiring if:

1. There is a way to see if this flag is successfully turned on during runtime?
2. There is a way to measure the performance improvement in doing so?

I have added this system flag to my distributed enterprise application but I am not sure if it is enabled and if there is a performance improvement on doing so.